# FlexSlider still loading slowly in Safari

Tags: performance, safari, flexslider, preload

I found a great solution for slow-loading Flexslider here: [Flexslider slow image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717097/flexslider-slow-image-load).

This solved the problem in all browsers except Safari. For some reason Safari still waits to load all images before displaying the first image.

Has anyone out there solved this one for FlexSlider/Safari?

Thanks!