# FlexSlider image distortion/jump when trying to load first image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

So my FlexSlider on [my site](http://skidoorinc.com) was loading slowly originally. I searched for some answers and saw [Flexslider slow image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717097/flexslider-slow-image-load). When I attempted to implement the most useful answers, some issues occurred. Now my site seems to distort the image, "blink" sort of when the image loads. (I've checked this specifically in Safari and Chrome.)

Does anyone have any idea how to make it load faster but not get messed up as it is doing currently?

Answer (score 1):

What I see is a reflow and repaint.
Specifying a width and height for all images inside your FlexSlider.

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="flex/images/slide1.jpg" alt="Residential doors." width="800" height="300"/>...
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="flex/images/slide2.jpg" alt="Commercial doors." width="800" height="300"/>...
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="flex/images/slide3.jpg" alt="One of our installations." width="800" height="300"/>...
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Compress your jpeg:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#CompressImages
And use Progressive jpegs

Minify flexslider.css and jquery.flexslider.js in production

It should load faster and not messed up your version.

Comment: When I added in the height and width, it actually stretched my images for some reason. But I did compress the jpegs.

Comment: In this example: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
They added
.flexslider {
min-height: 280px;
background: #FFF url(images/flex/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
You shoud have less flickering effect. For your website min-height: 200px;